# Show Shipping Cost based on Grand Total on Cart page

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, quote

I have a requirement where i need to show free-shipping if grand total is more than some value or else a fixed rate ( flat rate ) should be displayed on Cart page.

How can i set shipping cost based in Grand Total without knowing shipping or billing address.

Thank You.

Comment: Hello Marius, Above link is not helpful. I need to show rates in the Cart box. Is their any other way?

Comment: Read the answer I posted on that question to understand why you cannot have shipping rates based on Grand Total. Only on Subtotal.